# R Shiny's bindEvent with multiple inputs?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

With the recommended update to bindEvent as of Shiny 1.6.0,

I am trying to do create a multi-event listener with bindEvent. e.g.

```
observe({}) %>%  bindEvent(??, ignoreInit = T, ignoreNULL=FALSE)
```

Here are the input methods with observeEvent & observe:

```
observeEvent(c(input$a,input$b),{code})
```

or

```
observe({input$a; input$b; code})
```

both of these above options error out with bindEvent. A work around could be bindCache but that does not update if the inputs do.

Thoughts?

demo code (thanks @Zearpex):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("a", "Input A", value = 1),
  numericInput("b", "Input B", value = 2),
  verbatimTextOutput("output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    output$output <- renderPrint({
      cat("Something changed: a~", input$a, " or b~", input$b)
    })
  }) %>% bindEvent(? __ ?, ignoreInit = T, ignoreNULL=FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edits: Clarity & demo code

Comment: Your code snippet appears to be correct. Please supply a minimal _reproducible_ example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some testing, the following method does actually work. My error was else where.

```
%>% bindEvent(c(input$a, input$b), ignoreInit = T, ignoreNULL=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the list() method could fix your problem, if I understand it correctly.

Like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("a", "Input A", value = 1),
  numericInput("b", "Input B", value = 2),
  verbatimTextOutput("output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(list(input$a, input$b), {
    output$output <- renderPrint({
      cat("Something changed: a~", input$a, " or b~", input$b)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this could be a fix to your issue, if not I will be happy to try. ;)